# How do I break the 2GB barrier on Windows 2016 VM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, 32-bit, memory-management, windows-server-2016

I'm running a Windows 2016 64-bit VM on a QEMU-KVM hypervisor.
On that VM I'm running an old 32-bit application which uses ~3GB RAM and was linked with `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` to allow it to use more than 2GB RAM.

However, although linked with `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`, the application crashes when it tries to allocate more than 2GB RAM.

**The same problem does not happen on other machines**.
For example, the exact same application is running correctly on Windows 7 Enterprise (not a VM) and able to allocate ~3GB.

- Could the problem be related to the fact that Windows 2016 is running as a VM?
  Could QEMU-KVM hypervisor limit 32-bit application access over 2GB RAM?
- What could be the reason that it works on Windows 7 Enterprise but not on Windows 2016?
  Is there some configuration I need to make on the OS to allow it to use more than 2GB RAM?

---

## Update

I found out that the same problem happens when running the application on Windows 10, **non VM**.

So apparently, `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` is providing the application **more** RAM on Windows 2008 and **less** RAM on Windows 2016 and Windows 10...

- Does anyone have any idea why?
- Is there a way to configure Windows 2016 such that it would provide more RAM for an application linked with `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`?

Comment: Does that crashing application have any log files? What is the application? Any related events in Event Viewer? How much total memory do you have on the VM host, and how much have you allocated to the VM? Is it possible that there isn't enough memory to allocate to the application once it grows too large? Here is another post discussing this topic, but not necessarily regarding VMs. It does discuss giving different memory allocations to the kernel vs apps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686459/what-is-the-maximum-memory-available-to-a-c-application-on-32-bit-windows

Comment: @JimDiroffII The application is an internal tool we build and run, so we know what the error is. It stops with a memory allocation error (std::bad_alloc) after a total of 2GB was already allocated by the application. The VM has 16GB. Only 6GB allocated.There is definitely enough RAM in the VM. We added `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` to allow the application allocate more than 2GB and it worked well so far - until now.